# How to store selected radio button option value when click previous is pressed in android?

Tags: android

I am working on quiz application. I am displaying question and its options. i.e when next button is clicked next question with its options will be displayed. Also now I kept previous button. But I am getting problem with back button i.e for example I selected 3rd option in first question and went to second question and again clicked on previous button and came back to first question. The selected value is gone in the first question. How can I store the selected radio button value and how can i keep radio button checked=true again when pressed back or next button.

```
previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
   position= position-1;
   if (position>0)
   {
       next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       tv5.setText("" + (count--) + "/" + no.size());
       tv.setText(arr.get(position));
       showAnswer.setText(arr.get(position));
       rbd.setText(option_d.get(position));
       rdc.setText(option_c.get(position));
       rdb.setText(option_b.get(position));
       rda.setText(option_a.get(position));
   }
   if ((radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1))
   {
       skiped++;
       Log.i("skiped", "Please Select answer :" + skiped);
   }
}  
});
```

Comment: How you are shifting from one question to another. Are changing activity or are you doing this work in Fragment.

Comment: Using increament or decreament of postion of arr.get(position)..

Comment: when the next button is pressed, store the answer in an answer array for question position, when back is pressed, check for the answer in the answer array at that position and display it on screen

Answer (score 0):

Android has shared preference concept. Which can store your values application life time you can use it. But i feel as your requirement you don't application lifetime(install to  uninstall  life time). I would suggest you save it variable and keep passing it activity to activity using intent message passing mechanism